# #!/bin/bash exponent

Tags: shell-script

I'm having trouble running exponent operator in a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

number1=8
number2=2

sum1=$(( number1 ** number2 ))

echo "8 ^ 2 =" $sum1
```

it returns `expecting primary: " number1 ** number2 "`

I have also tried `^` instead of `**` but still it's not printing the desired result, 8^2 returning 64. I must be missing something, I just don't see what.

Any hint would be great, thanks.

Comment: What version of bash? how exactly are you running the script (not using `sh` I hope)?

Comment: that seems to be problem.. `./try.sh: 7: ./try.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " number1 ** number2 "` when using `sh ./try.sh`

Comment: @snw have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts on how to run your bash scripts

Comment: @spasic When run as `sh`, bash behaves quite different from when run as `bash`.

Comment: yeah, wanted to convey that I got same error as OP when running OP's script by calling `sh`

Comment: @D_Bye not necessary inside the `$(( ... ))` construct

Comment: @sp asic this solved my problem - interpreter directive..

Now it all makes some sense.

Comment: @roaima Hah! I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be running the script in the `dash` shell.

The error message that you quote is what `dash` outputs when it's failing to understand the `**` operator (`dash` doesn't have it).  It's the same error you get if you try to multiply something with nothing:

```
$ echo $(( 2 * ))
dash: 14: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " 2 * "
```

Make sure that you either execute your script directly (it has the correct `#!`-line after all), or by explicitly invoking it with `bash`:

```
$ bash script.sh
```

Comment: Okay so it worked running `$ bash script.sh`
But how come it not working doing `chmod +x script.sh` everything worked fine before adding the `**` to the script, what could have changed?

Comment: @snw stop providing an explicit shell to run your script. Instead, set it to be executable, and then just run it `./script.sh`.

Comment: I'm rather new at this.
I've been running `./script.sh` the above mentioned error occurs after adding `**`, it runs fine using `bash script.sh`. 
explicit shell?

Comment: mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts had the answer

Comment: @snw By "explicit" we mean saying "`bash`" before the script name. That way we _explicitly_ start `bash` with the script as argument. The site you link to gives an overview of how to make a script executable. You only needed `chmod +x script.sh` and then to run you script like `./script.sh`.  I was not aware thot you did not know this. It is hard to gauge someone's knowledge from just reading a question.

Answer (score 2):

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

This works well. Here is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  bash
clear

number1=8
number2=2

printf 'The sum of %d and %d = %d\n' $number1 $number2 $(( number1 ** number2))
```

And you just use the `chmod +x filename; ./filename`

If you use another shell, you may need to point the interpreter, and run in the correct way.

**BTW. Perfer use the `printf` than `echo`**

Comment: You forgot `\n` in the `printf` format string... Also, I see no benefit of using `printf` in this case. It merely complicates.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for mention the lost of newline. Actually in this script,echo do the same things as printf.But, it's a good practise in shell script to use printf. Just a suggestion.